# UIViewController not calling viewDidLoad & not creating UIView causing crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've been at this for a few hours now. I've got several View Controllers in this project and not a single one is causing issues but now all of a sudden this new one is. I even deleted it and made a "Test" View Controller, but no dice. The best I can tell it is not actually creating its view, thus when the view is referenced the app crashes. The test VC has no added or deleted code except for a log statement in the -viewDidLoad method. I am not overriding -loadView. I have tried adding the view to a subview, have tried pushing the VC into the Navigation Controller, I have even tried simply logging test.view. I have tried creating the VC with a NIB and have tried it without one. Absolutely nothing works at all. Any help will be appreciated.

**Where VC is being created inside of another VC. The log statment causes the crash. But so does adding as a subview and even pushing into nav controller.**

```
    TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"test view = ", test.view);
```

**Implementation of TestViewController.**

```
    @implementation TestViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"view = %@", self.view);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Nested VCs are not supported, calls to viewDidLoad (and similar methods) do not propagate.

Comment: I can not access this view from ANYWHERE in the project. I have tried it in multiple different classes even in the app delegate.

Comment: What messages show up in the debugger console when it crashes?  Or does Xcode flag a line of code or assembler with a green EXC_BAD_ACCESS marker or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say to double check all the connections from the view. Especially if its been copied or moved as its easy to leave a connection to an old VC

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using ARC in your project then dont check the autolayout box for the nib file. If you are using ARC then the connections of it to the file's owner can be the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you use xib,and  the items  is  copied from other xib or storyboard ,make sure the root view is exist,and drag tothe file's owner.